# How constraints/indexes slow down inserts

Tags: sql-server

What tools can we use to show that indexes are slowing down inserts in sql server? I know in development we can drop constraints and compare times, but in a production system how can we show that this is happening?

Comment: what is the context? do you want to proof such a delay exists at all? or want to measure it?

Comment: First and most powerful tool: Common sense. When indices are present, each insert causes re-arrangement of the indices (you can think of them as additional tables) and hence the required work increases. If you need to **measure** the amount of additional time that the use of indices introduces, the most reliable way is to (1) run a query with the indices defined, (2) drop the indices and (3) run the query again (IN THAT ORDER!!!), measuring each time the elapsed time.

Answer (score 3):

Indexes and constraints will slow inserts because the cost of checking and maintaining those isn't free. The overhead can only be determined with isolated performance testing. But unless you plan to drop indexes and constraints unilaterally by looking at insert overhead alone, the overhead information won't be of value.

I suggest you leave all constraints in place unless performance is a bigger concern than data integrity (I hope not). In production, identify indexes that are unused or provide little performance benefit to other DML by examining the [`sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-usage-stats-transact-sql) DMV. Consider that index tuning is a cost-benefit analysis, keeping in mind that data are inserted once but typically read many times.